# Update Plist data without erasing old data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, plist

I'm trying to make a file downloader application using swift and cocoa. I am using plist for the download history. Reading the data works however, writing the data will erase the previous data and replace it for the new data.

Here is the code

```
 let newdownloaditem = downloadList(root: [downloadListt(downloadURL: response.url!.absoluteString, fileName: response.suggestedFilename!)])
// This is a codeable method 
                                let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
                                encoder.outputFormat = .xml
                                
                                let pListFilURL = uniqueDataDir()?.appendingPathComponent("downloads.plist")
                                do {
                                    let data = try encoder.encode(newdownloaditem)
                                    try data.write(to: pListFilURL!)
// Here is the problem
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }


// Here is the codeable
public struct downloadList: Codable {
    let root: [downloadListt]
}
public struct downloadListt: Codable {
    let downloadURL: String
    let fileName: String
}
```

[Here is an image of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcucR.png)

The contents got erased

Thanks!

Comment: What is `newdownloaditem`? You need first to read the plist, then add you newItem, and then write it.

Comment: @Larme `newdownloaditem` is a codeable method used for reading and writing the plist

Comment: "writing the data will erase the previous data and replace it for the new data" You need to read the current saved data, add your new data to it, and save that. But I don't see where you read your previously saved data, where you append to it new new data. You seem to save (override) the new data only over the previous one.

Comment: I knew that, but I need to put the new code under the <array>

Comment: `let newItem = downloadListt(downloadURL: response.url!.absoluteString, fileName: response.suggestedFilename!); var allItems: [downloadListt] = []; allItems.append(contentsOf: previousList.root); allitems.append(newItem); let newList = downloadList(root: allItems); let data = try encoder.encode(newList)`. BUT, name you class/Sruct starting with an uppercase: `downloadList` => `DownloadList`, `downloadListt` is a bad name, it might be better to be `DownloadItem`, the double "t" won't make the diff.

Comment: @Larme Make an answer, I'll make it correct, you'll get more reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed replacing the previous data with your new one.

- You need to retrieve the previous data.
- Append your new data to it.
- Save that combination

```
let newItem = downloadListt(downloadURL: response.url!.absoluteString, 
                            fileName: response.suggestedFilename!)
var allItems: [downloadListt] = []
allItems.append(contentsOf: previousList.root)
allitems.append(newItem)
let newList = downloadList(root: allItems)
...
let data = try encoder.encode(newList)
try data.write(to: pListFilURL!)
```

Unrelated but recommended (it's convention):
You should starting naming your struct/classes with an uppercase: `downloadList` => `DownloadList`

I would avoid naming `downloadListt`, it's unredable it's hard at first look to make a difference between `downloadListt` and `downloadList`. Instead, name it maybe `DownloadItem`. More readable.